# Get subscribers to a specific price object in stripe?

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I'm trying to retrieve subscribers to a price object. Here's my approach, which works:

```
public void getSubscriptions() throws StripeException {
    Stripe.apiKey = KEY;


    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

Iterable<Subscription> subscrips = Subscription.list(params).autoPagingIterable();
    for(Subscription s : subscrips){
        if((s.getItems().getData().get(0).getPlan().getId()).equals("price_ABC123")){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(subscriptions);
}
```

The issue with this code is that its a bit slow. Is there a more efficient way to retrieve this info?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can filter by price id as shown here https://site-admin.stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list#list_subscriptions-price

```
public void getSubscriptions() throws StripeException {
    Stripe.apiKey = KEY;

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params["price"] = "price_ABC123";
    
    Iterable<Subscription> subscrips = Subscription.list(params).autoPagingIterable();
    
    for(Subscription s : subscrips){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```